# how to create an event in Google Calendar through android

Tags: android

I want to create an event in google calendar.

For that I read the sms from inbox and set the title as msg body.

I've set the event start time as msg received time but i've got an exception i.e.

```
com.gdata.util.ParseException:org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognisedException:http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities.
```

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at Google Calendar API (Java) for Android? http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/using.html

It is the best way to access the Google calendar from within you app.